Design and prove an ideal procedure for messaging IoT devices in large buildings to avoid jamming
So, here is the problem statement:
Assume a large building of 100 apartments divided on 10 floors. In every apartment there is a gateway and 1-N IoT devices connected to the gateway. The IoT devices are battery powered and therefore asleep most of the time. They wake up every 8 seconds and listens to incoming messages for 7 milliseconds before going back to sleep. When the devices receive a message, they wake up and stay awake for 20 seconds sounding an alarm before they go back to sleep. When the devices are awake they listen for incoming messages all the time and if they get a new message during the 20 second window then the timer is extended with 20 seconds from the time they receive the message.
Now, at some point we need to notify all the devices in the building so that they wake up and sound an alarm. The way it works is that the gateway receives a message from the cloud system they are connected to, and proceeds to send messages to the IoT devices. The gateways receive the message at the same time and from that point the gateway is required to work locally and make sure that all devices wake up. The messages are coded so that only devices that belongs to the gateway can receive it. It takes 2.6 milliseconds to send one message and a message can be sent as often as possible. Meaning that if the gateway sends a new message as often as it can, it will fit 2.69 messages in the wake window of a device.
The problem now is that if one gateway sends a message then it is occupying the "air window" and will jam another gateway if they send at the same time. Given that the IoT devices only wake up every 8 seconds for 7 milliseconds we need to define an algorithm that makes sure that all devices wakes up in reasonable time and are kept awake after that point.
I do not want to provide any limitations so you can assume that there is 100% jamming from each gateway in the building when it sends. In practice the signal strength is reduced over distance so a gateway at the bottom of the building will not influence a system at the top floor, however the algorithm should be as robust as possible so that we can handle as many devices in the close vicinity as possible. I assume that at some point we need to introduce some kind of signal strength factor and limit the number of IoT devices in each apartment to get a practical solution working.
Have at it!

What did you try?

Your problem looks like a "trial-and-error"-approach prone problem: you start with a first proposal. This does not hold against some condition, so you need to improve it into a second proposal. That one also doesn't hold against another condition, and you go on and on until either you find a solution or you prove that a solution cannot exist. Maybe you can handle this editing your question at every stage of your solution build-up.

We created a kind of algorithm that sets an initial delay for messaging between gateways and devices to reduce jamming and get as many devices awake and from that point transition to a different kind of messaging pattern where we message more often for a short amount of time to keep the devices awake.
It feels like its a good solution but I do not have the tools to formulate it mathematically and prove it, which is what I need
